# Как впихнуть actionbarsherlock в свой проект?

Tags: android, библиотеки, actionbarsherlock

> If you’re using the Eclipse
>   Development Environment with the ADT
>   plugin version 0.9.7 or greater you
>   can include ActionBarSherlock as a
>   library project. Create a new Android
>   project in Eclipse using the library/
>   folder as the existing source. Then,
>   in your project properties, **add the
>   created project under the ‘Libraries’**
>   section of the ‘Android’ category.

Проект из шерлока создал, но как его впихнуть в мой проект as a library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В свойствах проекта вкладка "Android" -> "Add library project".

Answer (score 1):

На [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project) есть подробная инструкция, как это сделать в эклипсе. Не для Шерлока конечно, а более общая инструкция.

Но зачем создавать проект из под шерлока - не знаю.

Comment: чтобы акшенбар и другая куча интересных примочек появились в 2.x, не?

Comment: А разве нельзя создать проект в эклипсе и прицепить туда actionbar? обычно так и делают.